# Should I have received 1099-MISC for bonus on new account opening?

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-1099, form-1099-misc

I received a $100 signup bonus for opening a new account with CapitalOne Checking account in USA. I kept a low balance and received very little (less than $1) interest. They didn't send 1099-INT because of low interest. But, they didn't send 1099-MISC for the bonus amount too.

**Question**: Should I have received 1099-MISC? Customer care said: 1099-MISC forms should have at least $600.

PS:

1. Chase bank sent me 1099-MISC for a just $50 signup bonus in 2019.
2. [This link](https://www.capitalone.com/support-center/bank/receive-tax-form) says bonus income may be reported on 1099-MISC.

Comment: What date did they put the bonus in your account? If there was a requirement to keep the account open for x days, it could have been in a different year.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep both (account opening + bonus) occurred in the same year (2020)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's up to the bank's policy whether they send it out if you're under the $600 threshold, but either way, you still have to report it on your taxes. Doctor of Credit has [a list](https://www.doctorofcredit.com/which-banks-send-out-1099s-for-account-bonuses/) of which banks report and which don't.

Comment: Should I report it as miscellaneous income? Tips, bonus? What kind of income/earnings?

Comment: I would report it as interest income. Could be misc income too and shouldn't make a difference.